# I am new to django and when I am trying to python manage.py runserver... I was getting an error below... what I have to do now? please let me know

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am new to django and when I am trying to python manage.py runserver, I was getting an error below. What I have to do now? Please let me know.

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()

OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>'
```

Answer (score 0):

have you done the initial steps:

```
python manage.py makemigrations

python manage.py migrate

python manage.py runserver
```

Comment: No, when I try to run python manage.py makemigrations, I am getting this 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()    and the error ends with ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Firstapp'.

Answer (score 0):

mention your app name in settings.py file, look for Installed_Apps and then put your app there (as shown below). Then run the server.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [

'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',

'your app name',

]
```

if you still getting an error then share your models.py, views.py and settings.py file here. Also tell what are you making in this project exactly.